# How to convert image(url format) to Base64 from Api response

Tags: api, flutter, dart, base64

I am trying to convert image(url format) from Api into BASE64 string but i don't know how to do it.Api response look like this

```
{
    "albumId": 1,
    "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
  },
```

i tried like this

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


    Future<List> getJson() async {

      String apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';

      http.Response response = await http
       .get(apiUrl);


      return json.decode(response.body); 
    }


    void main() async {

      List _data = await getJson();

      String _body = "${_data[0]['url']}";
    String data = base64.encode(_body.bodyBytes); Error here ..The getter 'bodyBytes' isn't defined for the class 'String'.

print("$data");  

      runApp(
        new MaterialApp(
          home: new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text('Json parse'),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
            body: new Center(
              child: new Text("khan   ${_data[0]['url']}"),

            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

i know i am doing it wrong, i am new to flutter. it will be great if someone also tell me how to show that string to image again. 
Note : I am storing that image string for Ecommerece cart purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can parse json string with

```
Future<List<Payload>> getJson() async {
    String apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';
    http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
    return payloadFromJson(response.body);
  }
```

Step 2: get base64 string

```
payloadList = await getJson();
    http.Response imageResponse = await http.get(
      payloadList[0].url,
    );
base64String = base64.encode(imageResponse.bodyBytes);
```

Step 3: show image with

```
base64String == null
                  ? Container()
                  : Image.memory(base64Decode(base64String)),
payloadList == null
  ? Container()
  : Image.network(payloadList[0].url),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

List<Payload> payloadFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Payload>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Payload.fromJson(x)));

String payloadToJson(List<Payload> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Payload {
  int albumId;
  String title;
  String url;

  Payload({
    this.albumId,
    this.title,
    this.url,
  });

  factory Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Payload(
        albumId: json["albumId"],
        title: json["title"],
        url: json["url"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "albumId": albumId,
        "title": title,
        "url": url,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  String base64String;
  List<Payload> payloadList;

  Future<List<Payload>> getJson() async {
    String apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';
    http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
    return payloadFromJson(response.body);
  }

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    payloadList = await getJson();
    http.Response imageResponse = await http.get(
      payloadList[0].url,
    );
    base64String = base64.encode(imageResponse.bodyBytes);

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              base64String == null
                  ? Container()
                  : Image.memory(base64Decode(base64String)),
              payloadList == null
                  ? Container()
                  : Image.network(payloadList[0].url),
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```